How to get KP F-stat in IV regression in R?
I am running an IV regression with fixed effects and clustered standard errors similar to the one below and would like to compute the Kleibergen-Paap (rank) F-statistic for weak identification. Is there any combination of packages that allows to do this in R?
Usually, I use fixest for estimations but the KP F-stat currently isn't implemented in a robust way and perhaps never will be: https://github.com/lrberge/fixest/issues/161
Generate data
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)

set.seed(123)

iso3c <- paste0("C", sprintf("%03d", 1:100))
year <- 2010:2019

df <- expand_grid(iso3c, year) |> 
  mutate(
    value = round(runif(n(), 5000, 500000), 0),
    z = sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE),
    x = sample(0:1, n(), replace = TRUE),
    population = round(runif(n(), 1000000, 100000000), 0),
    gdp = round(runif(n(), 10000, 2000000), 0),
    agree = round(runif(n(), 0, 100), 2)
  )

Fixest

library(fixest)

m1 <- feols(
  log(value) ~ log(population) + log(gdp) + 
  agree | iso3c + year | x / agree ~ z / agree,
  vcov = ~ iso3c,
  data = df
)

# estimation works ...
etable(m1)
#>                               m1
#> Dependent Var.:       log(value)
#>                                 
#> x                 0.6317 (1.660)
#> x:agree          0.0046 (0.0556)
#> log(population) -0.0360 (0.0431)
#> log(gdp)        -0.0362 (0.0372)
#> agree           -0.0034 (0.0260)
#> Fixed-Effects:  ----------------
#> iso3c                        Yes
#> year                         Yes
#> _______________ ________________
#> S.E.: Clustered        by: iso3c
#> Observations               1,000
#> R2                      -0.14947
#> Within R2               -0.26919
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

# ... but KP F-stat does not
fitstat(m1, "kpr")
#> Error in solve(t(Gmat)) %*% PI: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

PLM
With plm, I am struggling to even compute clustered standard errors, not to mention the KP F-stat:
library(plm)

pdf <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("iso3c", "year"))

m2 <- plm(
  log(value) ~ log(population) + log(gdp) + 
     agree + x / agree | . - x / agree + z / agree,
  effect = "twoways",
  data = pdf
)

# try to get clustered SE but plm not supported
modelsummary(m2, vcov = ~ iso3c)
#> Error: Unable to extract a variance-covariance matrix for model object of class
#>     `plm`. Different values of the `vcov` argument trigger calls to the  
#>   `sandwich` or `clubSandwich` packages in order to extract the matrix  
#>   (see `?insight::get_varcov`). Your model or the requested estimation  
#>   type may not be supported by one or both of those packages, or you were 
#>    missing one or more required arguments in `vcov_args` (like `cluster`).
#>        This error was raised:   no applicable method for 'estfun' applied
#>   to an object of class   "c('plm', 'panelmodel')" Note that the cluster
#>   variable in the formula cannot include missing `NA` observations.

sandwich::vcovCL(m2, cluster = "iso3c")
#> Error in UseMethod("estfun"): no applicable method for 'estfun' 
  applied to an object of class "c('plm', 'panelmodel')"

# SE look exceedingly large with clubSandwich
clubSandwich::vcovCR(m2, cluster = df$iso3c, type = "CR2") |> diag() |> sqrt()
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'clubSandwich':
#>   method    from    
#>   bread.mlm sandwich
#> log(population)        log(gdp)           agree               x         agree:x 
#>       1.0089572       0.9400815       1.6617743      23.9821805       3.6330824

# try to get KP F-stat but no diagnostics are computed
m2_summary <- summary(m2, diagnostics = TRUE)
m2_summary$diagnostics
#> NULL

Stata
For comparison, Stata's xtivreg2 command seems to accept both fixed effects and clustered standard errors and outputs the KP F-stat by default (see last line of output):
# export to Stata
haven::write_dta(df, "df.dta")

use df.dta, clear

// transform variables
generate log_value = log(value)
generate log_gdp = log(gdp)
generate log_population = log(population)

// set panel
encode iso3c, gen(country)
xtset country year

// create interactions (#-syntax not possible in IV spec?)
generate x_agree = x * agree
generate z_agree = z * agree

xi: xtivreg2 log_value log_population log_gdp agree (x x_agree = z z_agree) i.year, fe cluster(country)


Output (excerpt):
FIXED EFFECTS ESTIMATION
------------------------
Number of groups =       100                    Obs per group: min =        10
                                                               avg =      10.0
                                                               max =        10

IV (2SLS) estimation
--------------------

Estimates efficient for homoskedasticity only
Statistics robust to heteroskedasticity and clustering on country

Number of clusters (country) =     100                Number of obs =     1000
                                                      F( 14,    99) =     0.12
                                                      Prob > F      =   1.0000
Total (centered) SS     =   651.390692                Centered R2   =  -5.2059
Total (uncentered) SS   =   651.390692                Uncentered R2 =  -5.2059
Residual SS             =  4042.462153                Root MSE      =    2.119

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               |               Robust
     log_value |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
             x |   -3.41213   6.513033    -0.52   0.600    -16.17744     9.35318
       x_agree |   .1112556   .2117331     0.53   0.599    -.3037337    .5262449
log_population |   -.013885   .1699106    -0.08   0.935    -.3469036    .3191336
       log_gdp |   .0840052   .1213516     0.69   0.489    -.1538395    .3218499
         agree |  -.0584657   .1103253    -0.53   0.596    -.2746993    .1577679
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Underidentification test (Kleibergen-Paap rk LM statistic):              0.273
                                                   Chi-sq(1) P-val =    0.6013
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Weak identification test (Cragg-Donald Wald F statistic):                0.233
                         (Kleibergen-Paap rk Wald F statistic):          0.134



I am very positive about Stata (and not at all negative about R) -- but why mention Stata here at all? Your question is about R code.

Mainly to illustrate what I am after – I assume that many people use both Stata and R in their work, and that someone might know an equivalent implementation in R if I demonstrate it in Stata. I have removed the Stata tag so that Stata users will not be bothered.
